# How to use Android’s DrawerLayout.DrawerListener in a lambda expression?

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8, retrolambda

I've been exploring the concept of lambdas and how they provide a simpler syntax while implementing functional interfaces.

As per [this article](http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html), if there is one method it's quite easy to implement the lambda. So,

```
interface OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v);
}
```

Can be used like:

```
etDate.setOnClickListener(view -> Timber.i("the date is xyz"));
```

I've seen this work for interfaces with methods having different types of arguments as well, for example:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    void onSubscribe(Disposable d);
    void onNext(T t);
    void onError(Throwable e);
    void onComplete();
}
```

Can be used as

```
api.getData()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(response -> {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }, error -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "API returned an error: " + error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

So I was able to use onNext followed by onError this way.

But take a look at [the DrawerListener interface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1fbad11/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java#96):

I'm not able to use this using RetroLambda. The IDE doesn't suggest me to change the code to lambda and neither am I able to use it as such. I have to write it like this...

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        // My action goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
});
```

...which isn't neat. I am hoping for a solution to write it like:

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(view, offset -> {
        // My action goes here
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas are suitable only when there is only 1 abstract method to implement. In case of DrawerListener, there are 4 methods which need to be implemented. That is the reason you cannot code it the way you wanted. If you are adamant on using lambdas , you can create an interface that extends DrawerListener and provide default implementations for the methods in that. For this minSDK version should be 24 and jack should be enabled.

```
interface CustomDrawerListener extends DrawerLayout.DrawerListener{
    @Override
    void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset);

    @Override
    default public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    default public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    default public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
}
```

Then you can write add drawer listener as follows:

```
d1.addDrawerListener((CustomDrawerListener)(view,offset)->{
        // My action goes here
    });
```

build.gradle changes:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        //others
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    //other stuff
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. I guess this workaround isn't productive considering I have to create a new interface. The goal was to reduce the code not increase it. Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me.